# Is it possible to "serialize?" an object using annotations in Java

Tags: java, serialization

I'm not sure if "Serialize" is the proper word, however I want to create something that does this, for now:

```
private interface DummySerializer {
    default Map<String, String> serialize() {
        // Creates a Key/Value pair for all objects using the @DSerialize annotation.
    }
}

class DummyClass implements DummySerializer {
    private int hello = 0;
    @DSerialize private int world = 1;

}

Map<String, String> = new DummyClass().serialize();
// Print key/value pairs
```

This example would print out

```
world, 1
```

as the name of the variable was "world" that contained the `@DSerialize` annotation and the value of the variable was 1.

How could I go about doing something like this?

Could even go a step farther and also get the type of variable, for example "Integer" or "Float"

Comment: Look how other frameworks do it. Jackson for ex. Reflection  is powerful tool for meta-programming.

Comment: @SleimanJneidi - I wasn't aware it was done in other frameworks (or that it could be done), I'll take a look at Jackson. Thanks for the nudge.

Answer (score 0):

have a look at messagepack - it's a cross platform protocol for serialization (they call it binary json). the java implementation is based on annotations. as a nice characteristic, you can serialize a java object and then deserialize it to an object in a different programming language.

Strictly, this is not what you are looking for, I guess, but it will be able to do that job
http://msgpack.org/ ([java example here](https://github.com/msgpack/msgpack-java/wiki/QuickStart))